# icon in a button beside a name (p tag)

Tags: button, icons

i put buttons in a div and the buttons are supposed to have icons with names beside the icons, but after writing the codes the names keep showing before the icons.

i have tried using CSS and changed the div setup several times but no change.

Answer (score 0):

You must want a button which may look like
@ Button
here @ is icon and button is the name of button I am going to provide you some code which may help you to achieve this:

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button class="btn">
    <span>
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/null/comments--v1.png" alt="Image"></span>
    <span>Button</span>
  </button>



</body>

</html>
```

and CSS code

```
   .btn{
      display: flex;
      justify-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

Simply while using the icon you are change the src with your icon src url

Comment: Ps. sorry for the late response.